# Random intial conditions using finite element method

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, finite-element-method, finite-difference-method

How can we define the initial value for Cahn-Hilliard problem ([links](https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/1.3.0/python/demo/documented/cahn-hilliard/python/documentation.html)) using FEM in MMA?

Complete test code (I am using MIXED formulation for C1 Problem):

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
\[CapitalOmega]=ImplicitRegion[{0<=x<=1,0<=y<=1},{x,y}];
RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega],PlotRange->{{0,1},{0,1}}]
Mobi = 1.0; lame = 0.01;
op1 = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[t, x, y]\)\) - Mobi.\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(v[t, x, y]\)\)

op2 = v[t, x, y] - 
  200 u[t, x, y] (1 - 3 u[t, x, y] + 2 u[t, x, y]^2) + lame.\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(u[t, x, 
     y]\)\(\ \)\)

Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], N1] = 
 NeumannValue[Mobi* lame.u[t, x, y], {0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1}]

{nufun, nvfun} = 
  NDSolveValue[{op1 == Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], N1], op2 == 0}, {u, 
    v}, {t, 0, 100}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];
```

Comment: There are also other problems in your code: The `Dot`s after `Mobi` and `lame` have to be removed and you have not specified boundary conditions for `v`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I have checked the bcs, you may see Eq 5.1 from https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/1.3.0/python/demo/documented/cahn-hilliard/python/documentation.html

Comment: Yeah, so you have to specify them also in the call to `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of many ways to create "random" initial value conditions:

```
Ωdisc = ToElementMesh[Ω];
n = Length[Ωdisc["Coordinates"]];
u0 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{Ωdisc}, RandomReal[{-2, 2}, n]];
Plot3D[u0[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ωdisc]
```

It might be a good idea to use `Ωdisc]` also in the call to `NDSolveValues` instead of `Ω`.

Comment: @Herik Schumacher, this initial value definition not works. $0.625107,0.634007,<42>>, 0.639777,0.627036,0.625157, \ll 3151>>\},\{\text { Automatic }\} ]$ should
be a rank 2 tensor of machine-size real numbers.

Comment: That's probably because this is only an initial condition for `u`, not for `v`.

Comment: u[0, x, y] == u0[x, y]???

Comment: Yes, that's how you should use it. But `v` needs also initial conditions. And boundary conditions.